# how to get unique values from list column by group by user_id in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, set, pandas-groupby

input:-

```
    print(df)
```

```
device_id           ids
025c08d535a074b4    [8972]
025c08d535a074b4    [10595, 10595]
02612734f96edc43    [10016, 8795, 10019, 8791, 8351, 8791]
02612734f96edc43    [10016, 8795, 10019, 8791, 8351, 10052, 8345]
```

should output be unique list of  ids for each device_d like :

```
device_id           ids
025c08d535a074b4    [8972,10595]
02612734f96edc43    [10016, 8795, 10019,8791,8351,10052, 8345]
```

I try this by using :-->

```
    df=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('device_id')['ids'].apply(set))
```

but it not work properly it add `'` for before ids and return list like.

```
device_id           ids
025c08d535a074b4    [8972,'10595, 10595]
02612734f96edc43    ['10016,8795,10019,8791,8351,8791,'10016]
```

Comment: Slightly confused about your expected output... why does `8791` appear twice for the 2nd id ?

Comment: @ChrisA its typing mistake i correct this

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby('device_id')['ids'].apply(lambda x: np.unique(np.hstack(x)))
```

or if maintaining order is important, use [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) constructor with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.groupby('device_id')['ids'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.hstack(x)).drop_duplicates().to_list())
```

[out]

```
device_id
025c08d535a074b4                                    [8972, 10595]
02612734f96edc43    [10016, 8795, 10019, 8791, 8351, 10052, 8345]
```

---

If you need output as a `DataFrame`, just chain on [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.groupby('device_id')['ids'].apply(lambda x: np.unique(np.hstack(x))).reset_index()
```

[out]

```
          device_id                                            ids
0  025c08d535a074b4                                  [8972, 10595]
1  02612734f96edc43  [8345, 8351, 8791, 8795, 10016, 10019, 10052]
```

Comment: thank chris A for quick reply but it not match my requirement the it merge all lists in and return number of list

Comment: @PrajitKarande I've updatewd my answer - changed to apply `numpy.unique` before the groupby and then stack... is this what you were looking for?  ie `df['ids'].apply(np.unique).groupby(df['device_id']).apply(lambda x: np.hstack(x))`

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby('device_id', as_index=False).sum()
>>> grouped['ids'] = grouped['ids'].apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x), key=x.index))
>>> grouped
          device_id                                            ids
0  025c08d535a074b4                                  [8972, 10595]
1  02612734f96edc43  [10016, 8795, 10019, 8791, 8351, 10052, 8345]
>>>
```

Comment: hello your solution not working for my case  it split number and return like :- `[[, 1, 0, 3, 8, ,, , 7, ], 4, 2]`